# Creating a view in SQL - duplicate fields error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey there I am trying to learn SQL by trying to complete online questions and I'm trying to create a view.

I have created a SELECT query that works and now trying to turn it into a view, though when following the online instructions and enter the script that should create a view I come up with the duplicate field error.

I've looked into it and it may be "doctor.fullname" as a duplicate field but this is from another table. Andway I have deleted and still tried it but the error still appears.
I know there is probably an easy solution and sorry to bother you with this but it will be must appreciated.

```
CREATE VIEW patient_registration_form
AS
SELECT 
     patient.patient_id, 
     patient.nok_no,
     patient.f_name, 
     patient.s_name, 
     patient.sex, 
     patient.dob, 
     patient.marital_status, 
     patient.date_registered, 
     nok.tel_no, 
     nok.full_name, 
     nok.address, 
     nok.relationship, 
     doctor.doctor_id,
     doctor.clinic_no, 
     doctor.full_name, 
     doctor.address
FROM doctor, patient, nok
WHERE doctor.doctor_id = patient.doctor_id
AND nok.nok_no = patient.nok_no;
```

Comment: I still see doctor.full_name in this query (that conflicts with nok.full_name). You could alias one of the two or both with AS (e.g. `doctor.full_name AS doctorfull_name`)

Comment: And please stop using that awful implied join syntax. It is a SQL Antipattern and was replaced 20 years ago for goodness sakes!

Comment: @HLGEM You know I see that a lot, especially with mySQL. Not sure why; I wondered if some tutorial shows that.

Comment: whats the implied join syntax so I know for future purposes thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `full_name` listed... one for `nok.full_name` and one for `doctor.full_name`. One needs to be renamed such as `nok.full_name as nok_full_name`.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning several columns with the same name... `full_name` and `address`... even though they're from different tables.  In this case, you have to give them different aliases:

```
SELECT 
     patient.patient_id, 
     patient.nok_no,
     patient.f_name, 
     patient.s_name, 
     patient.sex, 
     patient.dob, 
     patient.marital_status, 
     patient.date_registered, 
     nok.tel_no, 
     nok.full_name as nok_full_name, 
     nok.address as nok_address, 
     nok.relationship, 
     doctor.doctor_id,
     doctor.clinic_no, 
     doctor.full_name as doctor_full_name, 
     doctor.address as doctor_address
```